# If ap is a pointer, why can I refer to its values through ap[i]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
class Vektor {
private:
    double *ap;
    int len;
public:
    Vektor() : ap(0),len(0) { } 
    Vektor(int n): len(n) { ap = new double [n]; } 
    double& front() { return ap[0]; }
    double front() const { return ap[0]; }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "n: "; cin >> n;
    Vektor a(n); 
    a.front() = 5; 
    cout << "a.front()=" << a.front() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused by the use of the `ap` pointer in this code. By definition of the constructor, `ap`, exempting the standard constructor, points to a memory space on the heap that contains `n` double variables. So surely, if I want to return any value for `front()`, I would have to define

```
double front() const { return ap*[0];}
```

and

```
double& front() { return ap*[0];}
```

rather than the way it is defined above, right? Or is `double* ap` simply the way to declare an array `ap`?

Comment: What do you expect `ap*[0]` to do?  It wont compile.

Comment: `[]` is a C++ operator defined to work on **pointers**. A more correct question would be to ask why `[]` works on arrays, that's the special case.

Comment: In absence of operator overloads, `a[b]` behaves exactly as `*(a + b)`.

Comment: Maybe this will help, https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

Comment: Do you maybe mean `(*ap)[0]`? (It's also incorrect, but better reflects the thought of getting what `ap` points at.)

Comment: It is because `ap` is not a pointer to the array. It is a pointer to the first element. For the rest, ask Dennis Ritchie.

Answer (score 1):

`ap` is a pointer to the first element of the array: `ap = new double [n];`. Pointers allow 
 you to access them with the `[]` operator (regardless of whether or not they point to arrays).
As mentioned in the comments, `a[b]` behaves like `*(a + b)`.